# Identifying the set of customers likely to purchase a product based on sales correlation

Tags: neo4j

Neo4j newbie here, but getting more ambitious with queries. I am attempting to retrieve the set of customers C2 who do not own product N but do own a product found in the set of products N2 that are also owned by the set of customers C who own product N. I am so close to having this query sorted and *think* this is it (given the product identified by SKU `123456`):

```
Start
N=node:node_auto_index(sku="123456")
match
  (C)-[:owns]->(N),
  (C)-[:owns]->(N2),
  (book)-[:owned_by]->(C2)
  WHERE NOT((C2)-[:owns]->(N))
return C2.name
limit 10
```

Am I even going about this in a sane way? What is odd is that it returns immediately when the result set is limited (limit 10 in the example), but when the limit is removed I receive the dreaded "Unknown Error" error in the web console (a look at the logs turns up nothing).

Insight appreciated!

**EDIT**

Michael Hunger certainly helped so I'm going to accept his answer however the problem wasn't due to a typo; I introduced that while making syntax substitutions to match the notation in my problem description because I was afraid my explanation was a bit convoluted. The solution however could trip up others so I'll explain it here. I was using the Neo4j web browser to prototype the Cypher query, and this works reasonably well, however it for some reason disallows responses containing more than 1,000 records. This is why the query was returning a response immediately when I limited it. When I subsequently limited the query by more than 1,000 rows, I was told the response was too large (more than 1,000 rows). When i remove the limit altogether I receive the "Unknown Error" error which I presume is just the browser admin's way of indicating (admittedly in a confusing way) that it can't return a response of more than 1,000 rows; why this is reported differently when no limit is used I'm not sure.

I came to this conclusion by running the query in the Neo4j shell, where it happily and immediately returned more than 1,000 rows. Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have a typo in your query: `book` instead of `N2`, I would also choose better Names. and if you use 2.0 start to use labels.

```
Start
N=node:node_auto_index(sku="123456")
match
  (C)-[:owns]->(N),
  (C)-[:owns]->(N2),
  (N2)-[:owns]->(C2)
  WHERE NOT((C2)-[:owns]->(N))
return C2.name
limit 10
```

for Neo4j 2.0

```
match (product:Product {sku:"123456"})<-[:OWNS]-(peer:Customer)
      -[:OWNS]->(other:Product)<-[:OWNS]-(target:Customer)
WHERE NOT( (target)-[:owns]->(product))
return target.name
limit 10
```

Perhaps you can create a [GraphGist](http://gist.neo4j.org) of your data model and some example queries for further discussion.